Properties of Discrete Wavelet Kernels
I am using PyWavelets for Wavelet analysis.
import pywt

for w in pywt.wavelist(kind="discrete"):
   wvlt = pywt.Wavelet(w)
   print(w, round(sum(wvlt.dec_hi), 5), round(sum(wvlt.dec_lo), 5))

For all discrete Wavelets, the sum of dec_hi is close to 0 and the sum of dec_lo is close to sqrt(2). Can someone explain that?

The low-pass filter also occurs in the refinement equation. That the sum has this fixed value is one of the necessary conditions that a non-zero solution of this functional equation exists. For instance the integral over both sides of the refinement equation has to give the same value, despite the different scales on each side.
The high-pass filter should at least zero-out constant signals. This is equivalent to the sum being zero.

Thank you! May I ask a follow-up question? What are the implications of the non-zero solution for signal reconstruction? Energy preservation?

I think you mean the solution of the refinement, two-scale or scaling equation. The solution, so it exists, provides the bridge between discrete and continuous signal processing. Formally you can do all the transforms with arbitrary discrete filter sequences. But if you want to zoom in using the cascade scheme, you will get random values and scales that are of no use.
